# Why does 'rspec spec' run faster and use less resources than 'bundle exec spec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler

Below are 3 random runs using `time rspec spec` vs `time bundle exec spec` on a fairly simple rails 3 app. Not using bundler is consistently faster AND it uses a lot less resources, 6% vs 17% cpu.

I'm sure it has something to do with bundler handling the dependencies but I'd like to understand this problem better. I try to practice TDD so of course I run my tests many times throughout the day. If using `bundle exec` is going to "cost" me in terms of speed and resources then I'm tempted to find a way to avoid the use of `bundle exec`.

I am using rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.9.2, rspec 2.3, bundler 1.0.10

```
rspec spec  0.47s user 0.13s system 6% cpu 8.758 total
rspec spec  0.47s user 0.12s system 6% cpu 8.521 total
rspec spec  0.46s user 0.12s system 6% cpu 8.528 total

bundle exec rspec spec  1.35s user 0.30s system 17% cpu 9.293 total
bundle exec rspec spec  1.39s user 0.31s system 17% cpu 9.749 total
bundle exec rspec spec  1.37s user 0.30s system 17% cpu 9.490 total
```

Comment: `bundle exec` behaves like a sandbox, I would say, it IS a sandbox. Think of gems you got via git (because of special patches not published so far - this are gems which are not reachable outside the bundle context)! So bundler loads/prepares your isolated gem environment. If you use gems via git you really need to use bundle exec, otherwise it will raises errors. - If you only have gems hosted by rubygems you can leave "bundle exec" away, because all your gems also can be found in the global scope.

Comment: Marginally OT, but if you are worried about test run times and you run tests frequently then you may want to give Spork a try. It basically preloads your test environment which Rspec then hooks into so it doesn't have to spin it up before each test. https://github.com/timcharper/spork

Comment: I have the complete opposite problem here.  Does anyone know why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982589/rspec-and-bundle-exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't quite *answer* your question directly as far as why one is slower. But I wanted to at least say for anyone who finds this later that it's generally only a coincidence that running executables without using `bundle exec` works. To quote the Bundler documentation:

> In some cases, running executables
>   without bundle exec may work, if the
>   executable happens to be installed in
>   your system and does not pull in any
>   gems that conflict with your bundle.
>
> However, this is unreliable and is the
>   source of considerable pain. Even if
>   it looks like it works, it may not
>   work in the future or on another
>   machine.

Comment: Well, I was mainly looking for a reason for using bundler even if it's slowing me down. And your answer has given me that reason :)

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that bundler has to dynamically parse all the gems in your gemfile before commencing the command.

Try

```
bundle exec gem list | wc -l
```

versus

```
gem list | wc -l
```

on a simple rails 3 project on this machine, I get 25 and 92 gems respectively.

Similarly try the same with a simple "ls" command, and you still see the speed difference.