# Rspec and bundle exec

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I ran into a performance issue with rspec.
If I do `rspec spec/*`, it takes over 2 minutes to load all my tests (I only have about 100 tests).
But if I do `bundle exec rspec spec/*`, it takes less than 10 seconds to load.

I found this post here that says exactly the opposite. [Why does 'rspec spec' run faster and use less resources than 'bundle exec spec'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222859/why-does-rspec-spec-run-faster-and-use-less-resources-than-bundle-exec-spec)

Any bundlr experts out there know what's going on?

p.s. the project is a pure ruby project, so no rails magic here.

Comment: What about just `rspec spec` (without wildcard)?

Comment: Hey Victor,  I tried doing that, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think this discussion can be useful

[Rspec execution speed footprint](http://old.nabble.com/rspec-execution-speed-footprint-td31413203.html)